# regex to exclude non golang files not working with inotifywait

Tags: regex, go, inotify

Below are the regex for filtering out all the non go files (i.e those with '.go' extension)

```
^([\S]*[^.][^g][^o]|[\S]*.[^g].|[\S]*..[^o]$|[\S]*[^.]..|[\S]{1,2})$

^([^.]*)($|[.]($|[\S]$|g[^o]$|[^g]o$|[^g][^o]$|([\S]+)\.($|.$|g[^o]$|[^g]o$|[^g][^o]$|[^.]{3,}$)|[^.]{3,}$))
```

You can test them here (click on try it 'Go' in the menu below the regex)

http://fiddle.re/80kvh6

http://fiddle.re/mhv1h6

While they seem to work correctly in go but not with `inotifywait`'s exclude filter (which uses posix ERE format)

I am trying to setup a "watch and reload" task in my Makefile for a golang project. Also i am assuming file or folders names dont have spaces.

Comment: Please try [`\.[^.][^o]$|\.[^g][^.]$|\.[^.][^.][^.]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/cT6dE2/4).

Comment: @stribizhev : Sorry mate. That wont work for all names without or with single char extensions eg `main.a` or `main` .

Comment: I did not assume there are 1-symbol extensions, true, but I added that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\.[^.][^.][^.]+$|\.[^.][^o]$|\.[^g][^.]$|\.[^.]$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT6dE2/6)

Or if you can group:

```
\.([^.][^.][^.]+|[^.][^o]|[^g][^.]|[^.])$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT6dE2/7)

See explanation:

- `\.` - a literal dot
- `([^.][^.][^.]+|[^.][^o]|[^g][^.]|[^.])` - a group of alternatives:

  - `[^.][^.][^.]+` - 2 characters other than `.` and 1 or more characters other than `.`...
  - `[^.][^o]` - a character other than a dot and a character other than `o`...
  - `[^g][^.]` - a character other than `g` and  a character other than a dot...
  - `[^.]` - a character other than a dot...
- `$` - right before the end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Got the issue. It seems `[:graph:]` not `\S` the class identifier for non-space chars in extended posix. The below is good to go.

`^[[:graph:]]*[^.][^g][^o]$|^[[:graph:]]{1,2}$|^[[:graph:]]*.[^g].$|^[[:graph:]]*..[^o]$|^[[:graph:]]*[^.]..$`

or even a better one from stribizhev comment `[^.][^g][^o]$|^..$|.[^g].$|..[^o]$|[^.]..$`

Comment: It is fine you found a working solution. Just note that grouping is a nice regex feature that makes regex patterns more readable and just shorter.

Comment: yeah.. had i done that, i wouldn't have even need to use the identifier. +1